# return null from task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

```
var hs = new HashSet<int>();

foreach(var item in mainclass)
{
    Task<List<Class1>> cl1Task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Class1>>(() =>
    {
        if (!hs_VersiodIDs.Contains(item.VersionID))
        {
             return new List<Class1>(.....);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    });

    Task.WaitAll(cl1Task );
}
```

It does not wait for task to finish. The problem is with return null so how can I return empty task ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes no sense for two reasons:

1. Starting a task that doesn't contain any long running code is useless. You will gain no advantage from this
2. Waiting for the task to finish right after starting it, completely negates the effect of the task: You are still blocking your main thread.

Change your code to this if the code in the task really is that simple:

```
foreach(var item in mainclass) 
{
    List<Class1> result;
    if (!hs_VersiodIDs.Contains(item.VersionID)) 
    { 
         result = new List<Class1>(.....); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        result = null; 
    } 
}
```

If the code inside the task really does something expensive, change your code to this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var item in mainclass)     
{     
    Task<List<Class1>> cl1Task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Class1>>(() =>     
    {     
        if (!hs_VersiodIDs.Contains(item.VersionID))     
        {     
             return new List<Class1>(.....);     
        }     
        else     
        {     
            return null;     
        }     
    });     

    tasks.Add(cl1Task); 
} 

// note, WaitAll is outside the loop, so now our tasks can all run in parallel
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: its not full code just the issue is coming when i return null

Comment: @Haider Then please show a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. There's nothing magical about "`return null;`", that by itself isn't the cause of whatever problem you're having.

Comment: sORRY.the problem was not in this function but in parallel.foreach i was adding to list in it and some how one two values were null used concurrentbag and all is working fine but performance is low . one again sorry to all

Comment: @Haider: "Performance is low" - I suggest you read my answer again and try to understand specifically the second reason for why your code makes no sense.

Comment: foreach(var item in mainclass)
 is in another task so no ui is blocked

Comment: @Haider: It still makes no sense. Starting a task and waiting for it right afterwards is completely useless. You will have exactly the same result as if there wouldn't be a task in the first place!

Comment: as i said previously this is not full code i am making service call e.g List<Class1> lst = proxy.GetData(); and there are 6 call (6 more task) i am waiting in loop beacuse i can group the exception of same ID call

Comment: @Haider: In that case you forgot nearly every important detail in your question... Please keep this in mind for your next one.

Comment: one again sorry for causing time wasting ,i will check my code thoroughly before asking question. only one question the perfermance has decreased(9min to 12 min) it was supposed to be that much? or i should shift to .net 4.5 cause when i searched i was there that 4 conncurentbag is slow and fixed in 4.5.

Comment: Are you sure this code works? Apparently [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) throws if `tasks` contains a null. Also, it looks like the argument must be a  `Task[]` not a `List<Task>`.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: `tasks` doesn't contain a `null`. It contains tasks which may return `null`. That's entirely different. You are right about the argument to `Task.WaitAll`, I fixed it.